# MacOS change display orders after restart

Tags: display, usb

In the company, we have Samsung S24E650 monitors - for each MacBook Pro, we have connected two of them by different kinds of USB-C hubs. When we unplug the monitors and plug it again monitors usually change the arrangement so we need to rearrange them in MacOS settings. Sometimes when we close the computer and awake them we have this issue too.

I'm sure that this is not an issue with the order of USB-C ports because I keep it always in the same order.

I don't have this problem when I work at home with my Iiyama monitor set. When I restart a computer display order is always correct.